# convert python 2.7 syntax to 3.3 - sum(map(len,P))

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax

I have a program that works with Python 2.7 but not python 3.3 Of course I know I need to use range rather than xrange, add () for print etc.. but the program has a lot of the 'map' method and it seems to create problems. When I got this error: `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()` I just casted it as a string and it worked.

What I couldn't figure out **how to convert** was this expression:
`sum(map(len,P))`
I get this error: `TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()`
but this time I'm not sure what to cast and how. 
I can post the entire code if that'd help.

This is how P is being initialized:

```
P, Q = [line.strip().lstrip('(').rstrip(')').split(')(') for line in input_data.readlines()]
P = [map(int, perm_cycle.split()) for perm_cycle in P]
```

Comment: Did you try: http://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html

Comment: Ghost.  `sum(map(len, [range(3), range(4)]))` returns `7` in Python 3.2.3, so your question does not give the information we need to even reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is `P` equal to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
P = [map(int, perm_cycle.split()) for perm_cycle in P]'
```

use

```
P = [list(map(int, perm_cycle.split())) for perm_cycle in P]'
```

The problem arises because you are trying to call `len(map(...))` later which works in Python 2 but not in Python 3 because Python 3 evaluates this `map` lazily (it's a generator there).  Run the explicit `list` around it to strip the laziness and get a real list.

*BUT* consider that you could maybe strip that `map` altogether because if you are only interested in the length of the list, there is no need to `map` it somehow.  `map`ping it won't change its size.

That would mean evaluate this:

```
sum(map(len, perm_cycle.split()))
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert each element of `P` to a list first:

```
map(lambda x: len(list(x)), P)
```

Or:

```
map(len, map(list, P))
```

A better way will be to follow @Alfe answer.

Here's a simple (though not perfect) rule: replace Python2 `map(...)` with `list(map(...))` in Python3.

Comment: +1, didn't realise the elements of P might be a list.

Answer (score 0):

In [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), `map` returns an iterator, while in [Python 2](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#map) it returns a list. You can construct a list from an iterator by calling `list(iterator)`.

So you need to change P to be :

```
P = [list(map(int, perm_cycle.split())) for perm_cycle in P]
```

Then the elements of P can be passed to `len`.

Another way to change it would be to have the expression be:

```
sum(len(list(item) for item in P)
```

You can always replace a `map` call with a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in Python 3 (in 2 you'd replace it with a list comprehension).

Comment: The problem is in the `P`, so applying `list` comes too late.

Comment: You're right - updated in response to the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

You can force `map` to be evaluated strictly with `list(map)`, so `len(map(len, P))` or similar expressions would remain valid in Python3.

Basically,

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major > 2:
    import builtins
    def map(f, *args):
        return list(builtins.map(f, *args))
```